# I'm trying to make c# calculation but it's wrong

Tags: c#, math, calculation

I'm currently making a new project on c# and i have a problem - calculations are wrong. My calculation is 1 * (1 + (1 - 160 / 180)) but it returns 2. I checked this in my calculator and the right answer is 1.11111...
Please help!
P. S. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`160 / 180` is integer division and will result in 0.

Try using `160.0/180` in order to promote the result a double.